# vs2010 stuck/freeze in any kind of scrolling

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, scroll, freeze

I have an annoying problem in VS 2010 SP1,

when ever I try to scroll up/down with the mouse, or keyboard or scroll bars the VS2010 going crazy and the screen freezes in some parts.

I restarted VS 2010 and even restarted the computer but nothing.
I uninstalled VS2010 and vs2010 SP1 and everything related to VS2010.

take a look at the examples:

[image]
[image]

Please help me..

Comment: Upgrade your graphics drivers, or disable hardware acceleration: Tools / Options / Environment / General / Visual Experience.

Comment: @RogerLipscombe I updated my graphics driver and uncheck Visual Experience and still nothing..

Comment: By any luck, you arent using any extensions that would require uninstalling the extension ?

Comment: @squelos I uninstall everything that can be related to VS.

Comment: See also this stackoverflow post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8646345/scrolling-in-visual-studio-causes-text-to-become-unreadable works on vs2012 and vs2010 for me

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I fix it by changing the Compatibility of devenv.exe, doing the following steps:

- right-click the devenv.exe file that located on:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   10.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe

- Choose properties.
- On Compatibility tab disable the following:

  1. Disable visual themes
  2. Disable desktop composition
  3. Disable display scaling on high DPI settings

  [image: Compatibility tab]

Comment: Thanks that saved my day :-) I searched a solution for over a week. And this helped. Altough I'm using VS2012

Answer (score 0):

The problem on my system was a screen mirroring driver (VNC) which disabled Aero which caused this issue. Disabling the driver and restarting fixed it.

I'm on VS2017 / Win7 x64 btw.